Using induction on n to show $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k \choose r} = {n + 1 \choose r + 1}$ for $1 \leq r \leq n$
Suppose we are asked to prove the following proposition:
Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k \choose r} = {n + 1 \choose r + 1}$ for $1 \leq r \leq n$
The book I am following chooses to prove this equality with induction as follows:

I agree with the body of this argument, but there are several components that I can't entirely agree with. First, their base case does not seem correct. That is, when $n = 0$, there are no valid values for r (based on the constraints outlined), meaning there are no statements to prove. Why, then, is the writer indicating that we can in fact examine the statement $\sum_{k=0}^{0}{k \choose r}$ = ${0 + 1 \choose r + 1}$, and that it is equal to $ 0 = 0 $? The first valid value should be n = 1.
The second issue I have is with the inductive step itself. In this context, if we assume the statement is true for $n = j$, where $j \geq 0$, then we know that $\sum_{k=0}^{j}{k \choose r} = {n + 1 \choose r + 1}$ for $1 \leq r \leq j$. To complete the inductive step, we must show that the statement is true for $ n = j + 1 $. That is,  $\sum_{k=0}^{j+1}{k \choose r} = {n + 1 \choose r + 1}$ for $1 \leq r \leq j + 1$. The solution in the answer key covers the cases in which $1 \leq r \leq j$ by combining Pascal's Formula with the inductive hypothesis to arrive at the desired equality. However, I noticed that the inductive hypothesis makes no claims about when $r = j + 1$. Accordingly, the reasoning used to prove equality for $1 \leq r \leq j$ is invalid when $r = j + 1$. Thus, would it be proper to also show that the statement trivially holds when $r = j + 1$? Namely, all of the terms in $\sum_{k=0}^{j+1}{k \choose j + 1}$ are 0 except for the final term, which is ${j + 1 \choose j + 1} = 1 = {j + 2 \choose j + 2}$.

You are right about what are you supposed to do about n=0 case. you can always start with n=1. The author have some conventions about when the summation upper bound is 0, it means empty sum which is usually conventially 0 as well, so that the answer holds. Other than that, I think you need to re read the induction step because r becomes r+1 but this has nothing to do with n.

Even more so, this statement is true: For 1<r<0 then above result for n=0 holds. The reason, other than summation convention, is that hypothesis is wont be contradicted, so it is opposite of a false which is true

I agree that the quoted induction hint is missing the case $n=j+1$, $r=j+1$. For a complete proof, please also mention that case.

@MahammadYusifov the issue I am having is not the summation bound. It has to do with the bounding of r. Are you saying that because there are no valid statements that can take the form given the constraints, there is no way to show that the statement can be contradicted?

The statement to be proven can be extended slightly to include $r=0$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom kr = \binom {n+1}{r+1}  \text{ for } 0\le r \le n$$
Then the base case can start from $n=0$ and not vacuous, but will become $LHS = 1 = RHS$.

To extend the statement to be proven in a different way, to include all $r$s up to infinity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom kr = \binom {n+1}{r+1}  \text{ for } 1\le r$$
Then both the base case can start from $n=0$ and not vacuous, and the induction hypothesis has no upper bound on $r$.

@LateGameLank, yes thats what I thought. At n=0 case, left side uses convention and right side holds for such r. In fact if r=0, it doesn't hold, so some condition is necessary. I think I said wrong about latter part.
